# Spring Security Webflux calling AuthenticationErrorHandler also on permitted endpoints

Tags: spring, security, spring-security, spring-webflux

I use Spring Security and an oatuh 2 Resource Server.
I have configured to allow some endpoints without authentication. Eg.: /actuator/health

**Authentication check is handled correctly and /actuator API calls are going trough without Authentication Header but still the ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint is called which logs an error in my case.**

I see that ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint.commence is called even twice on not permitted APIs and on permitted APIs it's called a single time. So something is calling the ServerAuthenticationEntryPoint.commence a second time.

Config:

I tried via permitAll:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
  @Bean
  SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(final ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
    //Disable Http Basic Auth and CSRF (not required because no cookies are used)
    .httpBasic().disable().csrf().disable()
    //All request need to be authenticated except OPTIONS and /actuator/**
    .authorizeExchange()
    //Allow all actuator calls
    .pathMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
    //Any other exchange need to be authenticated
    .anyExchange().authenticated()
    //Do not allow sessions
    .and().securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
    //Exception Handling
    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationErrorHandler())
    //JWT validation via OAuth Resource Server
    .and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().build();
  }
}
```

And via NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
  @Bean
  SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(final ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
    //Disable Http Basic Auth and CSRF (not required because no cookies are used)
    .httpBasic().disable().csrf().disable()
    //Allow all actuator calls
    .securityMatcher(new NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher(
        ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers("/actuator/**")))
    .authorizeExchange()
    //Any other exchange need to be authenticated
    .anyExchange().authenticated()
    //Do not allow sessions
    .and().securityContextRepository(NoOpServerSecurityContextRepository.getInstance())
    //Exception Handling
    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new AuthenticationErrorHandler()).and()
    //JWT validation via OAuth Resource Server
    .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().build();
  }
}
```